# Configure the order of the Combine pipelines execution

Tags: swift, combine

Suppose I want to draw a line on the screen. I have some user provided information in the `State` class. Now I want to hook up that state with the drawing logic in the `LineView` class.
I have a struct `Parameters` that my drawing methods use to render the line. `Parameters` can be created using information in the `State`.
I also need to account for updating of individual components of the `State` and call appropriate drawing methods to reflect the change. So when the color changes I need to call `recolorLine` and when line width changes I need to call `reshapeLine`. Finally I need to call both methods when `points` changes. I need to provide `Parameters` to all these functions. And this parameters must be constructed using all three of this inputs.
The example code:

```swift
class State {
    @Published var points: [CGPoint]
    @Published var lineWidth: Double
    @Published var color: CGColor

    init(points: [CGPoint], lineWidth: Double, color: CGColor) {
        self.points = points
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.color = color
    }
}

class LineView {
    var subs: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()

    func setup(state: State) {
        let params = CurrentValueSubject<Parameters, Never>(.init())

        // first pipeline
        // to update parameters I need all 3
        Publishers.CombineLatest3(state.$points, state.$lineWidth, state.$color)
            .map { points, lw, col in
                Parameters(points: points, lineWidth: lw, color: col)
            }
            .subscribe(params)
            .store(in: &subs)

        // second pipeline
        state.$points.sink { [weak self] _ in
            // here I need parameters updated with new points
            self?.reshapeLine(parameters: ...) // need parameters value here
            self?.recolorLine(parameters: ...) // need parameters value here
        }
        .store(in: &subs)

        // third pipeline
        state.$lineWidth.sink { [weak self] _ in
            // here I need parameters updated with new line width
            self?.reshapeLine(parameters: ...) // need parameters value here
        }
        .store(in: &subs)

        // fourth pipeline
        state.$color.sink { [weak self] _ in
            // here I need parameters updated with new color
            self?.recolorLine(parameters: ...) // need parameters value here
        }
        .store(in: &subs)
    }

    func reshapeLine(parameters: Parameters) {
        // UI code to redraw line points
    }

    func recolorLine(parameters: Parameters) {
        // UI code to change color of the line
    }
}


struct Parameters {
    // black box

    init() {}

    init(points: [CGPoint], lineWidth: Double, color: CGColor) {
        // black box
    }
}
```

To gain access to `params` I may replace for example the second pipeline: `state.$points.sink { ... }` with `Publishers.CombineLatest(state.$points, params).sink { ... }` but that would result in a bug where params value will sometimes be renewed via first pipeline and sometimes not.
I want them always to be renewed when second, third and fourth pipelines run.

Now, let's assume that this `Parameters` struct is just a black box. We must construct it using information in `State` and use it in the drawing methods. I know that if I split up this struct into individual components, the problem is going to disappear, but this `Parameters` struct is quite complex, so I was wondering if there is a way to do it without getting rid of this struct.

Essentially what I want to build here is pipeline that looks like this

[image: computational graph]

Here an arrow from A to B represents that B needs to subscribe on A and receive data from it. `Use latest` arrow from A to B represents that when computed, B need information from A, but B is not subscribed to A.
This is because there is no need for `reshapeLine`, for example, to be subscribed to `params` because its already subscribed to `lineWidth` which triggers `params` to be recalculated.
I just want `reshapeLine` to always fire **after** `params` have been recalculated.

Comment: Could you give a more realistic statement, without prejudicing the matter by introducing a bogus implementation, of what you're _really_ trying to do? Having a sink reach outside and fetch the value of a totally unrelated publisher (`val`) is just bonkers and goes against the entire spirit and purpose of Combine, as these are no longer pipelines at all.

Comment: @matt I updated my example to hopefully explain the problem clearer. I see that using `.value` on `CurrentValueSubject` in the other publisher is bad practise, but I couldn't find a better way to do it. Although of course doing it this way also doesn't work

Comment: Great diagram of desired data flow. But I don't see what *order* has to do with it. Sorry if I seem dense.

Comment: Also I don't quite get how the diagram involves Combine, which is about asynchronous events.

Comment: @matt An ordinary arrows represent subscription, i.e params are subscribed on lineWidth on so on. `Use latest` arrow just means that for example `reshapeLine` should subscribe on changes of `CombineLatest(lineWidth, points)` and use the latest version of `params` available to it

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with this question is that you keep providing what you think are partial solutions, rather than just describing your desired input/output and stating the base problem baldly. (This mistake is called an *xy problem*.) All your talk of "order", and your proposed pipeline, seem to be completely misleading (and somewhat nonsensical). Thus it is still not possible to determine what result you want.

So I have to guess.

My guess is that what you mean is that you have some inputs to a final output, but the last input is special in that a change in this input should *not* trigger an output; the last input (your "params") is *available* to the output but does not *trigger* the output.

The way to do that is introduce a filter that compares the current set of inputs arriving down the pipeline with the *previous* set of inputs arriving down the pipeline and removes any set of inputs that should not trigger the output.

As a simple example of the technique (though I do not claim that it solves your problem exactly, because as I say, I have not understood what your exact problem *is*), I propose three inputs:

- input A is a Pep Boy
- input B is a Marx Brother
- input Z is a number

And the following rules:

- If input A or input B changes, the output should process the latest values of all three inputs.
- But if input Z changes, the output should not process at all. The new value of input Z will be available the next time input A or input B changes, but a mere change in input Z will have no visible effect on the exterior world.

Okay, so here's that (as a view controller in an iOS project):

```
let inputA = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("mannie")
let inputB = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("groucho")

let inputZ = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1)

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let combiner = Publishers.CombineLatest3(inputA, inputB, inputZ)
    let pipeline = combiner.removeDuplicates(by: {
        $0.0 == $1.0 && $0.1 == $1.1
    })
    pipeline.sink(receiveValue: {
        print($0.0, $0.1, $0.2)
    }).store(in: &cancellables)

    inputA.send("moe")
    inputA.send("moe")
    inputB.send("chico")
    inputB.send("harpo")
    inputZ.send(2)
    inputA.send("moe")
    inputA.send("jack")
}
```

Here's the output:

```
mannie groucho 1
moe groucho 1
moe chico 1
moe harpo 1
jack harpo 2
```

The thing to notice is that the change in input Z from `1` to `2` did *not* produce `"moe harpo 2"` — it had no external effect. But when `"moe"` changed to `"jack"`, it turns out that the change in input Z is known, because we get `"jack harpo 2"`.

Note that I do not claim that *any* of this is identical to what you want — because I don't *know* what you want. But I do claim that this illustrates the general form of solution to the problem as I understand it. It might not be right (for you) to use CombineLatest or `removeDuplicates`, but *some* form of combination and *some* form of filter based on the previous value is the approach you need to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's almost what I want, this is how I could set up 'lower' part in my diagram, but I also need the 'top' part. This means that `inputZ` has to depend on `inputA` and `inputB`. There also have to be two pipelines: one that listens to `inputA` and only *uses* `inputZ`, and one that listens to `inputB` and only *uses* `inputZ`. Sorry I can't formulate the question clear enough) I have troubles explaining this, but I updated my question again) hopefully its a little bit more clear now